# verifying size of binary trees?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have a datatype in this way

```
datatype 'a bin_tree = 
    Leaf of 'a
  | Node of 'a bin_tree    (* left tree *)
           * int           (* size of left tree *)
           * int           (* size of right tree *)
           * 'a bin_tree   (* right tree *)
```

so an example for correct tree would be:

```
val tree1 =
  Node(Node(Node(Leaf 47, 1, 1, Leaf 38),
            2,1,
            Leaf 55),
       3,2,
       Node(Leaf 27, 1, 1, Leaf 96))
```

and an example for violating tree would be

```
val tree1false =
  Node(Node(Node(Leaf 47, 1, 1, Leaf 38),
            2,1,
            Leaf 55),
       4,2,
       Node(Leaf 27, 1, 1, Leaf 96))
```

How can I write a predicate test such that

```
- test tree1;
val it = true : bool
- test tree1false;
val it = false : bool
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive problem. Before solving recursive problems on trees, it is a good idea to have a firm grasp on recursion on lists. You could say that trees are generalisations of lists, or that lists are special-cases of trees: lists have one tail, trees can have any number of tails depending on the type of tree. So here is how you could reconstruct and solve the problem using lists:

If, instead of the typical list definition, you have a list that also memoizes its own length:

```
(* datatype 'a list = [] | :: of 'a * 'a list *)

datatype 'a lenlist = Nil | Cons of int * 'a * 'a lenlist
```

Then you can test that the stored length is in accordance with the actual number of values.

I'll start by creating a function that counts to illustrate the part of the function that performs recursion:

```
(* For regular built-in lists *)
fun count0 [] = 0
  | count0 (x::xs) = 1 + count0 xs

(* Counting the memoized list type disregarding the n *)
fun count1 Nil = 0
  | count1 (Cons (n, x, xs)) = 1 + count1 xs
```

The next part is that I'd like, in each recursive step, to test that the stored number `n` is also in accordance with the actual counting. What is the return type of this function? Well, the `test` function that you want should be `'a lenlist -> bool` and the `count` function that I made is `'a lenlist -> int`.

I will suggest that you make a `testcount` that kinda does both. But you can do so in many ways, e.g. by giving it "extra arguments", or by giving it "extra return values". I will demonstrate both, just to show that sometimes one is better than the other and experience will tell you which.

Here is a `val testcount1 : 'a lenlist -> bool * int` function:

```
fun testcount1 Nil = (true, 0)
  | testcount1 (Cons (n, x, xs)) =
    let val (good_so_far, m) = testcount1 xs
        val still_good = good_so_far andalso n = m + 1
    in (still_good, m + 1)
    end

val goodList = Cons (4, #"c", Cons (3, #"o", Cons (2, #"o", Cons (1, #"l", Nil))))
val badList = Cons (3, #"d", Cons (2, #"e", Cons (1, #"r", Cons (0, #"p", Nil))))
```

Testing this,

```
- testcount1 goodList;
> val it = (true, 4) : bool * int
- testcount1 badList;
> val it = (false, 4) : bool * int
```

This shows that `testcount1` returns *whether the numbers add up* and *the list's actual length*, which was necessary during recursion to test that the numbers add up in each step, but in the end is no longer necessary. You could wrap this `testcount` function up in a simpler `test` function that only cares about the `bool`:

```
fun test xs = #1 (testcount1 xs)
```

Here is another way to go about: There is something not so satisfying with the way `testcount1` recurses. It keeps calculating the `m + 1`s even though it is able to determine that a list (e.g. at `Cons (0, #"p", Nil)`) is broken.

Here is an alternate `val testcount2 : 'a lenlist * int -> bool` that stores a number in an extra argument instead:

```
fun testcount2 (Nil, 0) = true
  | testcount2 (Nil, _) = false
  | testcount2 (Cons (n, x, xs), m) =
      n = m andalso testcount2 (xs, m - 1)
```

This seems a lot neater to me: The function is tail-recursive, and it stops immediately when it senses that something is fishy. So it doesn't need to traverse the entire list if it's broken at the head. The downside is that it needs to know the length, which we don't know yet. But we can compensate by assuming that whatever is advertised is correct until it's clearly the case, or not.

Testing this function, you need to not only give it a `goodList` or a `badList` but also an `m`:

```
- testcount2 (goodList, 4);
> val it = true : bool
- testcount2 (badList, 4);
> val it = false : bool
- testcount2 (badList, 3);
> val it = false : bool
```

It's important that this function doesn't just compare `n = m`, since in `badList`, that'd result in agreeing that `badList` is 3 elements long, since `n = m` is true for each iteration in all `Cons` cases. This is helped in the two `Nil` cases that require us to have reached `0` and not e.g. `~1` as is the case for `badList`.

This function can also be wrapped inside `test` to hide the fact that we feed it an extra argument derived from the `'a lenlist` itself:

```
fun size Nil = 0
  | size (Cons (n, _, _)) = n

fun test xs = testcount2 (xs, size xs)
```

Some morals so far:

- Sometimes it is necessary to create helper functions to solve your initial problem.
- Those helper functions are not restricted to have the same type signature as the function you deliver (whether this is for an exercise in school, or for an external API/library).
- Sometimes it helps to extend the type that your function returns.
- Sometimes it helps to extend the arguments of your functions.
- Just because your task is "Write a function `foo -> bar`", this does not mean that you cannot create this by composing functions that return a great deal more or less than `foo` or `bar`.

---

Now, for some hints for solving this on binary trees:

Repeating the data type,

```
datatype 'a bin_tree = 
    Leaf of 'a
  | Node of 'a bin_tree    (* left tree *)
           * int           (* size of left tree *)
           * int           (* size of right tree *)
           * 'a bin_tree   (* right tree *)
```

You can start by constructing a skeleton for your function based on the ideas above:

```
fun testcount3 (Leaf x, ...) = ...
  | testcount3 (Leaf x, ...) = ...
  | testcount3 (Node (left, leftC, rightC, right), ...) = ...
```

I've embedded som hints here:

- Your solution should probably contain pattern matches against `Leaf x` and `Node (left, leftC, rightC, right)`. And given the "extra argument" type of solution (which at least proved nice for lists, but we'll see) needed two `Leaf x` cases. Why was that?
- If, in the case of lists, the "extra argument" `m` represents the expected length of the list, then what would an "extra argument" represent in the case of trees? You can't say "it's the length of the list", since it's a tree. How do you capture the part where a tree branches?
- If this is still too difficult, consider solving the problem for lists without copy-pasting. That is, you're allowed to look at the solutions in this answer (but try not to), but you're not allowed to copy-paste code. You have to type it if you want to copy it.
- As a start, try to define the helper function `size` that was used to produce `test` from `testcount2`, but for trees. So maybe call it `sizeTree` to avoid the name overlap, but other than that, try and make it resemble. Here's a skeleton:

```
fun sizeTree (Leaf x) = ...
  | sizeTree (Node (left, leftC, rightC, right)) = ...
```

Sticking `testcount3` and `sizeTree` together, once written, should be easy as tau.