# SML: Counting nodes

Tags: binary-tree, sml, treenode

My assignment is to write a function that will compute the size of a binary tree. This is the implementation of the tree structure:

```
datatype 'a bin_tree = 
    Leaf of 'a
  | Node of 'a bin_tree    (* left tree *)
           * int           (* size of left tree *)
           * int           (* size of right tree *)
           * 'a bin_tree   (* right tree *)
```

I was given this template from my professor:

```
fun getSize Empty = 0
    | getSize (Leaf _) = 1
    | getSize (Node(t1,_,t2)) = getSize t1 + getSize t2;
```

I was wondering if I need to manipulate this to agree with my tree structure in order to get it to work?

Comment: You're not supposed to "manipulate" that function, you're supposed to write your own function using pattern-matching on your own type.

Comment: This problem was already addressed in this Q&A: [verifying size of binary trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865921/verifying-size-of-binary-trees)

Answer (score 0):

The `'a bin_tree` type memoizes the size of each sub-tree. So if you're allowed to assume that the size that is stored is correct, you can return the size of a tree without recursion.

The template given by your professor is not for this type, but for another tree type that does *not* memoize the size. It demonstrates how you can calculate the size for such a tree by pattern matching and recursion, both language features of which you need to also use.

So the task is for you to write an entirely different function for the `'a bin_tree` type. You have to figure out what the right way to pattern match is. First off, the template for `getSize` does not add up: There are three cases with three constructors, `Empty`, `Leaf x` and `Node (L, x, R)`. But the `'a bin_tree` type only has two constructors, `Leaf x` and `Node (L, sizeL, sizeR, R)`.

So you want to read up on how to perform pattern matching on data types.